# Rails: Profile Picture Model Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, model-associations

I have a two models Users and Photos.

Right now, users can have many photos. I'm looking for the the best rails/database pattern for saying they have one profile picture. Which is one of the photos they have.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :emailAddress, :firstName, :lastName, :middleName, :phoneNumber
  has_many :photos
end
```

**Photo Model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  attr_accessible :image, :client_id
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

Should I add a :profilePicture attribute to User that points to an existing photoId, or should I add a new model called ProfilePicture, with a belongs_to :client, has_one :photo?

Any suggestions or links that can help me figure out the best way to set this up would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I made something similar where I called the profilePicture the avatar. the User model must have a avatar_id field in the table which is the photo_id for the pic used as the user's avatar. Note that the avatar_owner in a photo will only be assigned in photo instances that are avatar photos.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :emailAddress, :firstName, :lastName, :middleName, :phoneNumber, :avatar_id
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :avatar, :class_name => "Photo", :foreign_key => "avatar_id"
end
```

**Photo Model**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  attr_accessible :image, :client_id
  has_attached_file :image
  has_one  :avatar_owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "avatar_id"
```

end